# Creating associative arrays php for dynamic accordian

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I am creating a dynamic accordian with the values from database.

I am stuck in looping the array . Please help.

I have an array similar to this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => real estate
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => flatvcvjh
                [1] => villayuiuyidd
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => real estate
                [1] => iooi
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => y
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => real estate
                [1] => iooi
                [2] => painting
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => interior
                [1] => exterior
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => real estate
                [1] => iooi
                [2] => painting
                [3] => contruction
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => house
                [1] => compound
            )

    )

)

Following is the loop m using to get the above array
 foreach($parent_categories as $parent_category) {

         $sub_categories=//array of sub cat;
         $arr[]=$parent_category->name;

         $scat_name="";
         foreach($sub_categories as $sub_category) {
            //get sub categories
             $scat_name[]=$sub_category->name;
         }
         $subcat_name[]=$arr;
         $subcat_name[]=$scat_name;
         $project_categories[] = $subcat_name;
         $subcat_name="";

    }
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($project_categories);exit;
```

The above loop i tried is for 2 levels.

I need a 3 dimensional array with 3 levels of categories
like

```
category1
  subcat1
  subcat2
     subsubcat1
     subsubcat2
  subcat3
```

what changes will i have to make in the above loop I tried number of ways the above is what I get. Please help

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Answer (score 2):

Use recursive function

```
$menusList = array();
function dynamic_menus($menus) {
  foreach($menus as $index => $subMenu) {
   menusList[$index] = is_array($subMenu) ? dynamic_menus($subMenu) : $subMenu;
  }
 return menusList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert array to object first beacause you use

> > $sub_category->name    is to read object type

[Multidimensional array to object, specific way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410300/multidimensional-array-to-object-specific-way)

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php